# Diff Ignorar espaços em branco e quebras de linha

Tags: diff

Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta de diff capaz de ignorar todos os espaços em branco e quebras de linha?

Ex:

```
File1.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

File2.html
<html><head>
        <title>
            Title
        </title>
```

Mas na hora de comparar:

```
File1.html
<html><head><title>Title</title>

File2.html
<html><head><title>Title</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a ferramenta `diff` para isso.

Argumento `-b`: ignora alterações na quantidade de **espaços** em branco.

```
diff -b arq_1.txt arq_2.txt
```

Argumento `-B`: ignora alterações na quantidade de **linhas** em branco.

```
diff -B arq_1.txt arq_2.txt
```

Fonte: [documentação do `diff`](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/diff-Options.html).

Comment: onde foi que eu disse que tinha relação com git?

Comment: Opa, acho que bati o olho e confundi então. Você quer comparar dois arquivos e ver as diferenças ignorando os espaços e linhas em branco, isso?

Comment: ignorar as quebras de linha e espaços.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, veja se serve para o seu caso :)

Comment: Não deu, fiaz aqui numa maquina virtual, e o resultado não foi o que esperava.